# Changing Idle time for server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp, quickbooks

I have a user using quickbooks 2013 remotely from her house.  She logs in to our server and will be working but if she idles for too long the server makes her log back in. Normally this would be ok but not with quick books..

When she logs back in quick books tells her someone else is already in this file. I have to reset the user every time this happens.

Is there a way to fix the idle time with server 2003?

Also sometimes the user will go into quick book and buttons will be missing.. Again by me resetting her fixes the problem.

Thanks for the help

Comment: How are you "resetting" the user? Logging off her accounts?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a TechNet article detailing how to adjust the timeout/disconnect settings:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758177(v=ws.10).aspx